# What defines a sentence in MS-Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I know that the sentences collection is just a just a bunch of ranges, but I have not been able to determine exactly what criteria are used to decide where those ranges begin and end.  I have been able to determine that a period (.) a question mark (?) or an exclamation point (!) followed by one or more spaces is the end of a sentence and that the spaces are included in the sentence range.  I have also determined that if there are no spaces between what you and I would consider two sentences MS-Word considers it as only one sentence.

The problem is when you start putting in things like tabs, page breaks, new line characters etc. things become unclear.  Can anyone explain precisely or point me to some reference material what criteria MS-Word uses to decide where one sentence ends and another begins?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be based on a delimiter of a sentence ending type (e.g. ".","!","?"). If you explain what you are trying to do or post some code more people will be willing to help.

If you are concerned about combined sentences (e.g. This is a single Sentence.Even though it is deliminated) you could expand upon this basic methodology. Special Characters seem to be much harder to handle. So positn what you are trying to do would be suggested

```
Sub sent_counter()
    Dim s As Integer

    For s = 1 To ActiveDocument.Sentences.Count
        ActiveDocument.Sentences(s) = splitSentences(ActiveDocument.Sentences(s))
    Next s
End Sub

Function splitSentences(s As String) As String
    Dim delims As New Collection
    Dim delim As Variant
    delims.Add "."
    delims.Add "!"
    delims.Add "?"

    Dim ender As String
    Dim sub_s As String

    s = Trim(s)
    ender = Right(s, 1)
    sub_s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)

    For Each delim In delims
      If InStr(1, sub_s, delim) Then
        sub_s = Replace(sub_s, delim, delim & "  ")
      End If
    Next delim


    splitSentences = sub_s & ender
End Function
```

Comment: The programming task is actually simple and I finished it.  Wrote a macro to ensure that all "sentences" had the same number of spaces between them.  Can't count on user population to change the setting under proofing.  I just prompted user for the proper number of spaces, searched for punctuation marks, and inserted or removed spaces as required.

This is mostly for my own education now.  Normally  a sentence does end with a period, exclamation point or question mark but abbreviations like etc., Dr., and others confuse word about the end of a sentence.

Comment: I know those things can be added to the exceptions list but again I can't persuade several thousand users to do that and I don't have the clout to get the team that installs the office products to make it part of the standard install.  Things get even more unpredictable when you start adding tabs, new line, page break etc.  What I really want to know now is if there is an exact definition somewhere of what constitutes the end of a sentence as far as MS-Word is concerned.

Comment: Yes the end of a sentence is defined by a delimiter followed by at least 1 space or new line. `This is a sentence.` `This is all one sentence.Even though it has a period in the middle.` Since there is not such thing as a sentence Object and Microsoft does not distribute source it is difficult to determine the precise definition other than testing and handling all possible options as you see fit.

Comment: I still have no clear definition of what delineates a sentence.  When I get some space time I am going to do some more experimenting.  I am wondering if the correct question to ask isn't where does a sentence end but rather where does one begin?